# How to get the number of unread messages and the last message for each user in a SQL query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a message table like this:

```
message_id | body         | from_user_id | to_user_id | is_read | sent_date 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
1          | hello        | 23           | 31         | false   | 2 min ago
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
2          | thank you    | 28           | 31         | true    | 4 min ago
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
3          | how are you? | 31           | 28         | false   | 1 min ago
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
4          | a-ha         | 29           | 31         | false   | 6 min ago
```

I want to get the number of unread messages and the last message for the current user (for example user_id 31)

desired result:

```
from_user_id | to_user_id | body         | sent_date | unread_message_count 
-------------------------------------------------------------------
23           | 31         | hello        | 2 min ago | 1
-------------------------------------------------------------------
31           | 28         | how are you? | 1 min ago | 0
-------------------------------------------------------------------
29           | 31         | a-ha         | 6 min ago | 1
```

I used below code:

```
WITH ranked_messages AS (
    SELECT 
         messages.from_user_id, messages.to_user_id, 
         messages.body, messages.sent_date,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
         (PARTITION BY messages.from_user_id 
         ORDER BY messages.sent_date DESC) AS message_rank
    FROM 
         messages
    WHERE 
         messages.to_user_id = 31 OR 
         messages.from_user_id = 31
)
SELECT * 
FROM ranked_messages 
WHERE message_rank = 1;
```

but I want also `unread_message_count` per user.

for an example:

```
select 
     count(*) as unread_message_count 
from 
     messages 
where 
     to_user_id = 31 and 
     is_read = false and 
     from_user_id = 23
```

This should be calculated for each user who sends messages to the user, and vice versa

How can I achieve this result?

Comment: Thought of using group by user_id?

Comment: This code does not work
And it gives Error about the group by

Comment: Oh, my bad, it's in MySQL. You'd have to adapt

Comment: `SELECT count(message_id) as unread_messages_count, body FROM messages WHERE to_user_id = 31 AND is_read = false GROUP BY to_user_id ORDER BY sent_date DESC  LIMIT 1` Order by and group by were reversed

Comment: your codes does not work, because you must add `body` to the group by. I had tried all these ways
But these solutions do not work. thank you man

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(b.message_id) as unread_messages_count, b.to_user_id, (SELECT a.body FROM messages a WHERE a.to_user_id = b.to_user_id ORDER BY a.sent_date DESC LIMIT 1) as last_message FROM messages b  WHERE b.is_read = false GROUP BY b.to_user_id` Okay, my final try.

Comment: Build the query that gets and groups the amount of messages for each user, then sub-query the body into the results

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions.  I think this is the logic:

```
WITH ranked_messages AS (
    SELECT m.from_user_id, m.to_user_id, m.body, m.sent_date,
           SUM(is_read::int) OVER (PARTITION BY from_user_id) as cnt
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY m.from_user_id ORDER BY m.sent_date DESC) AS message_rank
    FROM messages m
    WHERE 31 IN (m.to_user_id, m.from_user_id)
)
SELECT *
FROM ranked_messages
WHERE message_rank = 1;
```

Comment: This code has a number of errors.
When the errors are solved.
For the cnt, the value is zero

Answer (score 0):

You could include the count as a nested query:

```
WITH ranked_messages AS (
    SELECT messages.from_user_id, messages.to_user_id, messages.body, messages.sent_date,
        select count(*) as unread_message_count from messages where (to_user_id = 31 or from_user_id = 31) and is_read = false,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY messages.from_user_id ORDER BY messages.sent_date DESC) AS message_rank
    FROM messages
    WHERE messages.to_user_id = 31 OR messages.from_user_id = 31
)
SELECT * FROM ranked_messages WHERE message_rank = 1;
```

Comment: `(select count(*) as unread_message_count from messages where (to_user_id = 38 or from_user_id = 38) and is_seen = false)` calculates all unread_message_count. I want  unread_message_count per user